# FPDF multicell alignment not working and still on the same line - php

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF to generate a large PDF in a table form. Now each page on the pdf table has 18 rows. A in each of those 2 colums can be fairly large but I cannot increase the cell width due to spacing issues. So instead I am trying to get those 2 cells to be multi-line but its is not working as seen in the picture. Wondering if anyone is able advise on this.
Also I need the space taken by the multiline to be minimal if possible or even better without changing the height.

```
        $current_y = $pdf->GetY();
        $current_x = $pdf->GetX();

        $pdf->MultiCell($width_cell[1], 7, $row['example'], 1, C, false);
        $pdf->SetXY($current_x + $width_cell[1], $current_y);
```

Thanks

[image: Example cell]

Comment: Consider using the [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) script.

Comment: @Olivier hello, wondering if you link would also work with my table example on the jsfiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/pilotman/aj48voye/2/

Also my aim is to get the table to resize accordngly and fit on one page as seen in the original table on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use html table for FPDF
here is the link
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php

Comment: Do you know if it will shrink the table to fit on 1 page before I start the implementation?

Comment: honestly not sure but you can make the link i sent for testing  with some long content